# How extremly Magento 1 perfomance can be Optimized

Tags: magento-1.9, database, category, performance, optimization

I am using magento 1.  My site is developed with porto theme. If i look porto theme demo it has better perfomance than mine.

I ma using Simple Helix shared hosting for my site. Also,  using full page caching module.

Issue is when my site loads it takes 10-15 seconds for home page, 20-25 seconds to load category page and 20-25 seconds for product detail page.

There are only **25 products** in mysite and hardly **20 categories**. On home page there is 3 sections called **Best Seller**  and **Featured Products**  ,  Footer Contains CMS page links etc.

I have Done following tasks to optimize my magento:

1. Gzip Compression (Htaccess code)
2. Leverage Browser cache(htaccess code)
3. Enable Keep Alive
4. Css Optimization
5. js Optimization
6. Images Optimization
7. Flat Catalog
8. Magento caching
9. Full Page Caching

I have done all above techniques to optimize my magento site. Also, did remove some blocks which was taking load  but still it takes 10-15 seconds.

How can i figure out why my magento taking too much time to load?  What tools i need to use to figure out load taking elements?
When site loads first it takes 10-15 second. as i have used **Full page caching** when second time page will load it will take 2 to 3 seconds.

How can i optimize it to load in 3-4 second when load first time?
What else you recommend?  How can i optimize category page and Product detail page?

Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: for optimize performance you should take a look first which requests take more time you can get get idea which part taking more time to load.

Comment: please provide your site link i will look and provide solution.

Comment: Simple Helix has a lot of bad reviews.  Are your servers and hosting located near or in the area where your intended customers and you are located?  Is your internet connection fast enough?  Have you checked if compilation is disabled?  Can you test the site on GTmetrix or pingdom?

Comment: @fja3omega Simple helix is magento hosting partner so i thought that would be very powerful and professional enviroment for magento site.

What other hosting option you recommend to optimize the site?

Comment: @Yogesh  How can i check which requests take much time to load?  is there any tools for that?

Comment: @jack https://gtmetrix.com/ , https://tools.pingdom.com/ , https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ this all site provide an information about that.

Comment: Yes, they provide that information like browser cache,  gzip, defer parsing etc. all that tasks are done.  Still no speed.

Answer (score 0):

shared hosting, this can be a problem. 
but you need to start from running magento profiler or installing [Aoe_Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler)
it will show if you have some problems with templates or custom code, etc.

if no magento issues, then question to your hosting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Which hosting would be best for magento site with 20K products, 20K Customers and daily traffic of 10K ?  What hosting enviroment you recommend?

Comment: any hosting is good for this shop, but you need to make sure it works properly. check your code with profiler first.

Comment: Trying to check with AOE  Profiler. But aoe profiler not loading anything in footer.   I did check video and configured everything fabian explained in document but no luck.  Magento ver:  1.9.3.2

Comment: profiler in admin panel